# Select2 slow in Angular2 app but not in fiddle

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 (4.0.3) in an Angular2 (2.0.0) project.  I am experinceing slow loading times in the angular app but not in a jsFiddle I created.

The fiddle below has an object named listOfItems that containts the exact data as my Angular project.  I hard-code a JSON string (from my app) and convert it to this object.  It takes about 30 milliseconds the load select2.
https://jsfiddle.net/7e8v12fL/3/

I am only timing the actual select2 setup call.

Here is the code:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (this.fullList.length > 0) {
        if (changes['fullList'] != null) {
            this.listOfItems = this.convertInputList(this.fullList);
            var startTime = new Date();
            $(this.el.nativeElement).select2({
                placeholder: 'aaa',
                tags: false,
                width: '100%',
                allowClear: true,

                data: this.listOfItems
            });
            var endTime = new Date();
            alert(endTime - startTime);
        }
    }
}
```

NgOnChanges fires when my input variable changes.  First it fires when listOfItems is empty but I skip the select2 step.  Then it fires when listOfItems has 1,557 items and it takes over 3,000 milliseconds.

If I hard-code the options in the select tag it's fast.  It's just when I am loading the data.

Why is it so much slower in my Angular2 app than it is in the fiddle?
Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Update:
I copied the hard-coded array from jsFiddle into my angular app and it's still slow on the angular side.